# UnsatisfiedLinkError in FlutterJNI.loadLibrary

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, google-play-console, openweathermap, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have recently updated my weather app on Play Store which is built in Flutter version 3. It is working properly in many devices. However, when I check analytics on Google Play console it is showing crashes in some devices saying:

**io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary**
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

[image]

How can I fix it? is there anyone who experienced the same problem?